# Translation of Hex Colours to RGB Colours?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, rgb

Apparently Illustrator and Photoshop uses different colour settings - Illustrator uses RGB and Photoshop uses some hex/HTML-like colour system with a combination of letters and numbers. Is there any way of 'translating' a RGB colour swatch to Photoshop easily?

Comment: Photoshop uses a whole range of color systems. You should be able to change what it uses in the color picker settings.

Comment: Btw, what OS/platform are you on? (curious)

Comment: Do you understand how hexadecimal numbers work? It's just a way to represent numbers in Base-16. `A=10`, `B=11`, `C=12`, `D=13`, `E=14`, `F=15`. So `0xFF = 15*16+15 = 255`. You can even have Google calculate it for you: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/easy-tip-to-convert-hex-to-decimal/

Comment: @Moshe: Mac OS X.

Comment: @CalvinHuang: and to finish your series, 10(hex) = 16(decimal). `@`the OP: Each column represents (16 raised to the power of the column number)+ a differential, with the right-most column being column 0. This is how base-10 numbers work as well

Answer (score 7):

Both Illustrator and Photoshop use hexadecimal values! The screenshot below: Illustrator is on the left, photoshop is on the right [image]

You can use either RGB or hexa between the two programs.

To transfer simply select your swatch and open the Color Picker and select the hexadecimal value.

Fun fact: The first two letters/numbers of hexadecimal value colors are the Red color.
The second pair are the Green colors, and the third pair are the Blue colors.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

If you want to match up PANTONE swatches... 
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/330/330728.html

Comment: Nice answer. (With both Photoshop and Illustrator, you couldn't put a little overlay on each screenshot to label each one?)

Comment: I'll add to your fun fact that each "part" of the hex value represents a value between 0 and 256. Translating the numbers is a matter of translating the hex number to decimal.

Comment: mosh...0 and 255.

Comment: There are 256 values. 0 through 255 = 256

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth underlining that hex is just an alternative notation for RGB 8 bit-per-channel values, e.g. #DB7093 means *exactly* the same as rgb(219,112,147). So you can freely translate between them without any issues.

In contrast, HSB, Lab, CYMK and Pantone etc are different colour spaces/systems/models and so  a direct or exact conversion is not necessarily possible.